# What should be the ideal length of a variable name in Java?

Tags: java, naming

I try to find out not according to semantics but weight. I mean, should I take care when set a long name to a variable?

Comment: The length that provides the most readability and clarity of purpose.

Comment: Exactly 27 characters.

Comment: @Snowman do you have a padding strategy? or do you always come up with exact 27 character meaningful names :)

Comment: @Chip That's why programming takes so long. It is pretty difficult to find a meaningful name for any variable when the requirement is the length must be exactly 27 characters. But oh boy is it worth it.

Comment: As short as possible. As long as necessary.

Comment: Never mind you lose all the benefits of having the variable name being exactly 27 characters if the length is not exactly 27!!

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Is there an excuse for short variable names?](http://programmers.stackexchange.com/questions/176582/is-there-an-excuse-for-short-variable-names)

Comment: If you can't come up with a good name, inline the variable. This only works if the variable is used in one place of course

Answer (score 5):

The comments to the original question have the best answers:

- The length that provides the most readability and clarity of purpose. – [Robert Harvey](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/users/1204/robert-harvey)
- As short as possible. As long as necessary. – [CodesInChaos](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/users/8669/codesinchaos)

Answer (score 0):

There's no set length which can be said to be the ideal length for a variable name (in Java or in any other language, pretty much). There are, however guidelines you can use when deciding:

1. The most important thing about the variable name is that it clearly shows the purpose of the variable, and that it is clearly readable, as mentioned by @RobertHarvey. Remember that you're not writing read-only code, and that some poor sod is going to have to go through that code in a few months' time in order to do some maintenance. If you're unlucky, the poor sod in question might even be you :P
2. It's mostly included in point 1, but avoid ambiguous names, or names that are too similar to other variable/class/function names already in use.
3. Follow language conventions. In Java, that generally means naming variables in camelCase. In some cases (not sure about Java) that might mean that naming a loop index i is perfectly acceptable, for example, despite the fact that it's not all that informative a name.
4. All else being the same, prefer shorter names, but only as long as it doesn't impact readability. If you find yourself trying to contort variable names in order to shave a character or two off, please stop and give a bit of thought to said poor sod who's gonna have to read the code in a few months' time.

Comment: It is ok for coding conventions, what I'd like to know is what happens in the JVM. I mean, is there a high level cost for declaring long variables names?